# I've got JavaScript value compare error (e.g. 3>10 return true)

Tags: javascript

I have been writing a function for web page, which should do the followings:

1. I can set max value;
2. I can set available value which must no larger than max value;
3. If I never change 'available', it will always same as 'max';
4. When I tune down 'max', when 'max' < 'available', 'available' will go down as 'max' (which is rule 2);

My problem is

1. when I set 'available' less then 10, and when I tune up 'max' to
   above 10, 'available' will suddenly set to 'max' unexpectedly;
2. same things appear when I set 'available' between 10 to 100, when I tune up 'max' to above 100, 'available' will suddenly set to 'max' unexpectedly too;

(one of the error conditions for you to try)
 -in the web page:

1. set 'max' to 7 (whatever less than 10);
2. set 'available' to whatever less than 'max';
3. change 'max' to whatever larger than 10;

-> 'available' will change to equal 'max' and Compare result is 'TRUE'

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code please. thanks.
I've tried on 3 machines.

```js
// (not important) simply for knowing if 'user' changed the value of 'available'.
var ref =0;

function function_a(max){
//  (not important) for output reference only. *************************************
  document.getElementById('display_index').innerHTML = (max < document.getElementById('available').value);
  document.getElementById('display_index1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('available').value;
        document.getElementById('display_index2').innerHTML = max;
//  (not important) for output reference only. *************************************


// core function start: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 if (document.getElementById('available').value > max){
  document.getElementById('available').value = max;
  document.getElementById('display_available').innerHTML = max;
 }
 
 document.getElementById('display_init').innerHTML = max; 
 document.getElementById('available').max = max; 
 
 if(ref != 1 )
 { 
  document.getElementById('available').value = max;
  document.getElementById('display_init').innerHTML = max;
 }
// core function end ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
}

function function_b(ava){
 ref = 1; 
 document.getElementById('display_init').innerHTML = ava;
 
 if (ava > document.getElementById('max').value){
  document.getElementById('available').value = document.getElementById('max').value;
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- *************** Output for reference *******************-->
Output : <b><span id="display_available">0</span> / <span id="display_init">0</span></b></p>

<p><label>Available : </label>
<input type="number" id="available" min="0" max="0" value="0" onchange="ref = 1; function_b(this.value);">
</p>

<p><label>Max Value: </label>
<input type="number" id="max" min="0" max="99999" value="0" onchange="function_a(this.value);">
</p>

<!-- *************** End of Output for reference *******************-->


<!-- *************** Main Function *******************-->
<fieldset>
<p>
Compare result: <span id="display_index"></span> 
</p>
Values before function changed :  Checking if <br>
Available: [<span id="display_index1">0</span>]  > 
Max : [<span id="display_index2">0</span>]
</fieldset>
<!-- *************** End of Main Function *******************-->
```

Comment: Yes, `"3" > "10"`. You should use numbers, not strings.

Comment: Use parseInt javascript function and pass your 'ava' and 'Max' variable into it and compare i.e. if (parseInt(ava) > parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value))

Comment: Thanks all, yes, that's the reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is propably comparison of strings -> "3" and "10". So you should use parseInt function to parse them to the numbers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Thank you very much! that's the reason!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Frédéric in comments; When comparing values you'll want to use numerics, not strings. Use `parseInt(value, radix)` to make the string an integer (second parameter, radix, is to force the parseInt to treat the value as a decimal)

For example:

```
if (parseInt(document.getElementById('available').value, 10) > parseInt(max, 10)) {
```

Your full code:

```js
// (not important) simply for knowing if 'user' changed the value of 'available'.
var ref =0;

function function_a(max){
//  (not important) for output reference only. *************************************
  document.getElementById('display_index').innerHTML = (parseInt(max,10) < parseInt(document.getElementById('available').value,10));
  document.getElementById('display_index1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('available').value;
        document.getElementById('display_index2').innerHTML = max;
//  (not important) for output reference only. *************************************


// core function start: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 if (parseInt(document.getElementById('available').value,10) > parseInt(max,10)){
  document.getElementById('available').value = max;
  document.getElementById('display_available').innerHTML = max;
 }
 
 document.getElementById('display_init').innerHTML = max; 
 document.getElementById('available').max = max; 
 
 if(ref != 1 )
 { 
  document.getElementById('available').value = max;
  document.getElementById('display_init').innerHTML = max;
 }
// core function end ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
}

function function_b(ava){
 ref = 1; 
 document.getElementById('display_init').innerHTML = ava;
 
 if (parseInt(ava,10) > parseInt(document.getElementById('max').value,10)){
  document.getElementById('available').value = document.getElementById('max').value;
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- *************** Output for reference *******************-->
Output : <b><span id="display_available">0</span> / <span id="display_init">0</span></b></p>

<p><label>Available : </label>
<input type="number" id="available" min="0" max="0" value="0" onchange="ref = 1; function_b(this.value);">
</p>

<p><label>Max Value: </label>
<input type="number" id="max" min="0" max="99999" value="0" onchange="function_a(this.value);">
</p>

<!-- *************** End of Output for reference *******************-->


<!-- *************** Main Function *******************-->
<fieldset>
<p>
Compare result: <span id="display_index"></span> 
</p>
Values before function changed :  Checking if <br>
Available: [<span id="display_index1">0</span>]  > 
Max : [<span id="display_index2">0</span>]
</fieldset>
<!-- *************** End of Main Function *******************-->
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that's the reason!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `parseInt`, consider using `-`

```
var three = '3';
var ten = '10';
if(three-ten>0)//3-10===-7
```